# jQuery HoverIntent is not a function

Tags: functions, jquery, errors

I am working on a [site](http://wonderland.opteradev.com) that uses jQuery for a number of functions but I am having a repeating error:

> hoverIntent is not a function

I have referenced similar questions on this forum and they almost universally say that it is due to multiple references to jQuery, however, I have carefully reviewed the code and the source code and cannot find any duplicate references.

There is just this one in functions.php

```
// Load jQuery
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("js/jquery.dropmenu.js"), false);
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("js/jquery.dropmenu2.js"), false);  
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

I would really appreciate another set of eyes to help pinpoint and resolve this dilemma.

Comment: Are you by any chance enqueuing jquery after the script that depends on it?

Comment: Good question, but jQuery is listed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the HoverIntent is optional for the drop menu plugin. I turned that off and everything is working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`wp_register_script()` Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) the first parameter `handle` should have a unique name.

If we look at the paramters of the `wp_register_script()` function it breaks down like this:

`wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );`

So your `wp_register_script()` function should also break down into a similar way:

```
wp_register_script( 'dropmenu1', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/jquery.dropmenu.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
```

Comment: Howdy, I am not sure how this would be implemented. Does it replace the entire wg_register_script block or just the one with dropmenu in it? I tried both and I still get the error.

Comment: Where are you putting your current code? Are you using any hooks like `wp_enqueue_scripts`? [This is a good example of how registering and enqueueing works in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Example_of_Automatic_Dependency_Loading)